# MongoDB Aggregation function

Tags: mongodb

I have the following JSON Documents in Mongo collection named "Movies"

```
{
      "_id": "5ed0c9700b9e8b0e2c542054",
      "movie_name": "Jake 123",
      "score": 20,
      "director": "Jake"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5ed0a9840b9e8b0e2c542053",
      "movie_name": "Avatar",
      "director": "James Cameroon",
      "score": 50,
      "boxoffice": [
        {
          "territory": "US",
          "gross": 2000
        },
        {
          "territory": "UK",
          "gross": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5ed0a9630b9e8b0e2c542052",
      "movie_name": "Titanic",
      "score": 100,
      "director": "James Cameroon",
      "boxoffice": [
        {
          "territory": "US",
          "gross": 1000
        },
        {
          "territory": "UK",
          "gross": 500
        }
      ],
      "actors": [
        "Kate Winselet",
        "Leonardo De Caprio",
        "Rajinikanth",
        "Kamalhaasan"
      ]
    }
```

I run the below query which finds the maximum collection of a country of various movies. My intention is to find the maximum collection and the corresponding territory.

```
db.movies.aggregate([
    {$match: {"boxoffice" : { $exists: true, $ne : []}}},
    {$project: {
                "title":"$movie_name", "max_boxoffice": {$max : "$boxoffice.gross"}, 
                "territory" : "$boxoffice.territory" } }
          ])
```

I get the result as follows. How do I get the correct territory that corresponds to the collection?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0a9630b9e8b0e2c542052"),
    "title" : "Titanic",
    "max_boxoffice" : 1000,
    "territory" : [
        "US",
        "UK"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0a9840b9e8b0e2c542053"),
    "title" : "Avatar",
    "max_boxoffice" : 2000,
    "territory" : [
        "US",
        "UK"
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

Avatar and Titanic has collected more money in US. I wanted territories to display the values of them

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0a9630b9e8b0e2c542052"),
        "title" : "Titanic",
        "max_boxoffice" : 1000,
        "territory" : "US"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0a9840b9e8b0e2c542053"),
        "title" : "Avatar",
        "max_boxoffice" : 2000,
        "territory" : "US"

    }
```

Comment: Please update your post with expected output also, and also explain the reason for the output.

Comment: @palaѕн let me know if it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific requirement, you can use [`$set (aggregation)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/). `$set` appends new fields to existing documents. and we can include one or more `$set` stages in an aggregation operation to achieve this like:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "boxoffice": { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      boxoffice: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$boxoffice",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.gross", { $max: "$boxoffice.gross" }]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      boxoffice: { $arrayElemAt: ["$boxoffice", 0] }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "title": "$movie_name",
      "max_boxoffice": "$boxoffice.gross",
      "territory": "$boxoffice.territory"
    }
  }
])
```

[**Mongo Playground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FBLP8t6QSv0)

Comment: @palash I have accepted it as an answer. But is there a simpler way to do it?